# Perform Selector Casting

Tags: objective-c, reflection, casting, performselector

There's a really strange behavior going on with float / double / CGFloat casting on the result of performSelector:

Why does this work?

```
BOOL property = (BOOL)[self.object performSelector:@selector(boolProperty)];
NSInteger property = (NSInteger) [self.object performSelector:@selector(integerProperty)];
```

And this doesn't

```
CGFloat property = (CGFloat) [self.object performSelector:@selector(floatProperty)];
```

At first I tried to do this:

```
CGFloat property = [[self.object performSelector:@selector(floatProperty)] floatValue];
```

But I ended up getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS runtime error.  I already figured out a hack to solve this issue but I would like to understand why it works with Integer and Bool and not with floating point types.

My hack:

```
@implementation NSObject (AddOn)
-(CGFloat)performFloatSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
  NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:aSelector]];
  [invocation setSelector:aSelector];
  [invocation setTarget:self];
  [invocation invoke];
  CGFloat f = 0.0f;
  [invocation getReturnValue:&f];
  return f;
}
@end
```

Then:

```
CGFloat property = [self.object performFloatSelector:@selector(floatProperty)];
```

Comment: The first ones "work?"  performSelector is supposed to return an `id`... perhaps casting `id` as a long is safer than casting it as a float.  See the [NSObject protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBGHFG).  I still wonder why the protocol is separate from the class, but whatever.

Comment: @stevesliva They work and I've got unit tests to prove it. The accepted answer explains why it works.

Comment: @JulianJ.Tejera - the answer **wholly** justifies the airquotes around "work!"

Comment: casting `id` to `BOOL` and `NSInteger` should not be allowed in ARC. Is this MRC then?

Comment: I'm using ARC and Xcode didn't complain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `performSelector` method only supports methods that return nothing or an object. This is covered in its documentation where it states:

> For methods that return anything other than an object, use `NSInvocation`.

Your "hack" is just the correct way of calling a selector which returns a non-object.

The reason why it appears to work for integer and boolean methods is to do with the way values are returned by methods. The return type of `performSelector` is `id`, an object pointer type. Integer-like values; which includes `NSInteger`, `BOOL` and object pointers; are often returned in a general purpose register, however floating point values are usually returned in a floating point register. The compiler will always load the result from the register used for returning `id` values and then perform any action required by the cast. For integer and boolean values the loaded value is probably correct and the cast is a no-op in those cases, so everything (appears to) work. For floating point values the loaded value is incorrect - it is not the value the called method has returned as that is in a different register.

Note calling non-object, non-void, selectors with `performSelector` can cause memory issues under ARC - the compiler will usually warn if this might be the case.

The `NSInvocation` way of calling a selector works for non-object return types as one of its arguments is the method signature itself. Using the signature `NSInvocation` is able to determine the type of the return value and how it is returned, and therefore correctly return it to the caller.

HTH

Comment: I guess I have to read a little bit more about registers. I suppressed the compiler warnings with #pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `NSInvocation`, you can use the `objc_msgSend` functions directly (this is what the compiler translates message calls to):

```
BOOL (*f)(id, SEL) = (BOOL (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend;
BOOL property = f(self.object, @selector(boolProperty));

NSInteger (*f)(id, SEL) = (NSInteger (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend;
NSInteger property = f(self.object, @selector(integerProperty));

CGFloat (*f)(id, SEL) = (CGFloat (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend;
CGFloat property = f(self.object, @selector(floatProperty));
```

Note that you must cast it to a function pointer with the exact signature of the method to call it correctly; here the methods take no parameters, so the function only has the 2 "hidden" parameters, `self`, and `_cmd`. If the methods took parameters, you would have to add more parameters to the function pointer type.

Also, note that for `struct` returns, you will need to use `objc_msgSend_stret` in place of `objc_msgSend`, but everything else exactly the same as above.

Comment: It's really interesting to learn new ways of doing things but I think I'll stick to the NSInvocation solution because the syntax is objective-c like, and cleaner (at least to me). Thanks!